While statement with and conditional behaviour
I have a very simple script that attempts to check the status of an API call up to a maximum of five times, with a one-second pause between each attempt. Script simulates an API call to check the status by setting a response variable to 400. If the response is 200, it sets the stop variable to "true" and prints a success message. Otherwise, it prints a failure message with the response code.
      counter=0
      max_attempts=5
      stop=false

      while [ $stop = "false" ] && [ $counter -lt $max_attempts ]; do
        echo "Attempt $((counter + 1))"

        # Simulate API call to check status
        response=400

        if [ "$response" = "200" ]; then
          stop=true
          echo "Call is successful."
        else
          echo "Call failed with response code: $response"
        fi

        ((counter++))
        sleep 1 
      done

      if [ "$stop" = "true" ]; then
        echo "stop is true, exiting loop."
      else
        echo "Reached maximum attempts, exiting loop."
      fi

I don't understand why is stopping after first iteration
| Attempt 1
| Call failed with response code: 400


Use xtrace (bash -x yourscript to get a more precise idea of how it fails, and update your question accordingly.

(Separately, your quoting is backwards: [ $stop = "false" ] should be [ "$stop" = false ] -- that's a class of bug that https://shellcheck.net will catch automatically; also, log status updates meant for human operators to stderr, not stdout)

(Also, you probably want ((++counter)) instead of ((counter++)) -- the latter behaves badly when combined with set -e. Granted, you shouldn't be using set -e at all...)

@CharlesDuffy - shellchecker.net help me solve it out.

@CharlesDuffy - you can take my answer and post it, so I can accept as being yours :)

I wouldn't bother with stop at all; use for ((counter=0; counter < max_attempts; counter++)); do ...; done, and use break to exit the loop immediately on success.

(You don't really care how you exited the loop, just what the value of response is after it exits.)

@chepner - I've solved in that way, I wanted to solved it with while loop, as I'm a beginner in bash and wanted to see what I was doing wrong :)

since this is bash, it's better to use [[ $stop = "false" && $counter -lt $max_attempts ]]. Always prefer the [[ version when available

My first thought was that you should refactor the loop so that the condition of the while actually checks what you want to check rather than using the "stop" variable.  Put more logic into the function that "simulates response" (I presume this is actually an invocation of curl or similar).  For example, I think the loop is a lot clearer if you write it as something like:
#!/bin/bash

counter=0
max_attempts=5

simulate_response() {
        echo "Attempt $((counter + 1))"
        case $(( $(date +%s) % 7 )) in
        0)
                response=200
                ;;
        *)
                response=404
                echo "Call failed with response code: $response" >&2
                ;;
        esac
        test "$response" = 200
}

main() {
        while
                ! simulate_response &&
                [ "$((++counter))" -lt "$max_attempts" ]
        do
                sleep 1
        done

        if test "$counter" = "$max_attempts"; then
                echo "Reached maximum attempts; request failed." >&2
                return 1
        else
                echo "Got response: $response"
        fi
}

main "$@"


Note that I'm using test in most places rather than [ because I think it is a lot cleaner.  There are some who will argue that you should use [ because it is a shell built in while test invokes an external program, but I strongly suspect that has been true in less than 1% of existing shells since the mid 90s.

solved it with help from @CharlesDuffy
      counter=0
      max_attempts=5
      stop=false
    
      while [ "$stop" = false ] && [ $counter -lt $max_attempts ]; do
        echo "Attempt $((counter + 1))"
        
        # Simulate API call to check status
        response=400
        
        if [ "$response" = 200 ]; then
          stop=true
          echo "Call is successful."
        else
          echo "Call failed with response code: $response"
        fi
        
        counter=$((counter+1))
        sleep 1
      done
    
      if [ "$stop" = true ]; then
        echo "stop is true, exiting loop."
      else
        echo "Reached maximum attempts, exiting loop."
      fi


Your answer is not particularly helpful for others. What have you changed?

Your quotes are still backwards.  You don't need to quote literal strings that do not contain whitespace (value in $IFS, but "whitespace" is simpler).  You do need to quote variables.  You ought to write [ "$stop" = false ]  This bug will burn you one day, and cause many hours of painful debugging.

Is the only difference the change from ((counter++)) to counter=$((counter+1))? This should only be an issue if set -e is enabled, which is not a good idea, and isn't shown in the script.
